# Android use System app without root to write to file

Tags: android, root

I am currently developing an AOSP ROM and I need to make a system app which is able to write data to CPU text files. The thing is I am able to do it while I have root access but the ROM needs to be flashed and provided to a non-root phone which should still be able to use that system app.

Could someone with prior experience please provide some guidance ?

Comment: `"CPU text file"`? what is it?

Comment: @pskink I am talking about the files which hold scaling governors etc usually found at "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu%d/cpufreq/scaling_governor";

Comment: as far as i know a system app is an app placed on this path `/system/app` so once you have ur app in that path i think it will be able to write the files

Comment: @Yazan nope that is not possible ... I need to write this app for a vendor and they have compiled a ROM already ... I guess the only way to it would be to add a system service in the framework itself.

Already putting the app in my system/priv-app folder and it still needs root to modify cpu state files